# complication with a query two crossed fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with a query, I hope you can help me. I have next table.

[image]

I want you to spew me "id_union" where "id_petitioner" as "id_requested" crossing.

for example:

on data from that table the "id_union" 1 and 4 there is a junction and vice versa. I want those records.
thanks for reading my question

I want to print all records where "id_petitioner" and "id_requested" as "id_requested" and "id_petitioner" are equal, where there is cross :)

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Please include the data in you question (you can type it in, preceded by four spaces).  One important reason is that links can go stale.  Also, include your desired results.

Comment: Was it really necessary to post an image? Why couldn't you post that simple table as plain text?

Answer (score 1):

Use a self-JOIN:

```
SELECT t1.id_union, t2.id_union
FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN yourTable AS t2 
ON t1.id_petitioner = t2.id_requested 
    AND t1.id_requested = t2.id_petitioner 
    AND t1.id_union < t2.id_union
```

The last condition keeps it from showing both `1, 4` and `4, 1`.